# sf auth:jwt:grant hanging - no terminal output

Tags: salesforcedx, jwt, cicd

I have been working on creating a CICD pipeline with my developer org and github actions. I have done the following:

Connected app created
Profile added to connected app with API permissions.
User created and added to Profile'
Certificate created and added to connected app

I was testing this locally on my workstation but running the following command (without secrets) just runs forever.

```
SF_LOG_LEVEL=debug sfdx auth:jwt:grant -i <ConsumerKey> -f server.key -o <SalesforceUsername>
```

Struggled a little bit with this then went to the usual places for troubleshooting. Dug into the log file in my home directory and saw:

> {"level":30,"time":1708192388630,"name":"sf:AuthInfo","msg":"Access token has expired. Updating..."}

followed by:

> {"level":30,"time":1708193033710,"name":"sf:AuthInfo","msg":"Saved auth info for username: myUsername"}

If I look at the login history I have the account authenticating multiple times a second if I let the terminal hang.

Really confused by this outcome and could really use a hand understanding where to look next.

Running this on a macos workstation.
Using SF CLI v. 2.26.10

Answer (score 0):

Issue was related to role scope:
I needed to add "Perform Requests at any time" to the scope of the app.
Wasnt able to refresh the JWT.

Now we are authenticated.